# PayPal Return URL not working

Tags: button, paypal, return

I have a form like these:

```
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='co_1331738237_per@gmail.com'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Nueva compra en mi web'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='10.15'>
<input type='hidden' name='page_style' value='primary'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://someurl.com/reserva-realizada/'>
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://someurl.com/reserva-cancelada/'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='0'>
<input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='NOMBRE'>
<input type='hidden' name='last_name' value='APELLIDOS'>
<input type='hidden' name='night_phone_b' value='TELÉFONO'>
<input type='hidden' name='custom' value='Nota'>
<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='es'>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"> 
<input type='hidden' name='country' value='ES'>
```

The problem is that after pay i need to sing up the user in my site and the return it's not working. When I tried to pay something in the sandbox of paypal it doesn't return…

Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

go to your PayPal merchant account-->profile-->Selling Preferences-->Website Payment Preferences-->Auto Return for Website Payments turn radio button to on,default it should off.i hope this help you.

Comment: The cuestion is.

If I do that on my account and other user try to pay using my form the return should work?

Comment: At PayPal they did their best to make sure the all thing is the most complex possible.